# sorting list of cards

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists:

```
card_candidates = ['9D', '9S', '3S', '0D']
card_order = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
```

I want to be able to sort the first list with respect to the second lists order. So the sorted card_candidates should look like this:

```
sorted_candidates = ['3S', '9D', '9S', '0D']
```

The '0' is just the value of 10, just wanted to make all the cards the same length. If there is a tie, like with '9D' and '9S', then the letters will need to be sorted instead. So far I have just done this:

```
sorted_candidates = []
for x, y in zip(card_candidates, card_order):
    sorted_candidates.append([x[0] for x in card_candidates])
return sorted(sorted_candidates)
```

I know that this is not even close to being right, I just don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Produce a dictionary mapping your sort order characters to a number, we'll sort by those:

```
sort_map = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(card_order)}
```

You can now use this mapping to sort your cards, including the second letter to break ties:

```
sorted_candidates = sorted(card_candidates,
                           key=lambda card: (sort_map[card[0]], card[1]))
```

The sort key takes the first character of each card and translates that to an integer from the `sort_map` dictionary, which then inform the `sorted()` function of the correct sort order. In case of a tie (equal card value), cards are sorted in clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades order (assuming you use `C` and `H` for clubs and hearts).

Creating a mapping up front keeps the sort within O(NlogN) time complexity; you could do the same with `card_order.index(card[0])`, but then you invoke a `list.index()` call *for every sorted element*, and `list.index` needs to scan the list, producing a O(KNlogN) sort (where K is the length of the `card_order` list).

Demo:

```
>>> card_candidates = ['9D', '9S', '3S', '0D']
>>> card_order = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
>>> sort_map = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(card_order)}
>>> sorted(card_candidates, key=lambda card: (sort_map[card[0]], card[1]))
['3S', '9D', '9S', '0D']
>>> sorted(['9D', '9S', '9C', '9H'], key=lambda card: (sort_map[card[0]], card[1]))
['9C', '9D', '9H', '9S']
```

Comment: +1 for the complexity analysis. Quite a few questions related to sorting cards in python exist on here, this answer is the best by a huuuge margin :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need any additional data structures, the `card_order` list is totally enough to sort your cards using this simple one-liner:

```
card_candidates = ['9D', '9S', '3S', '0D']
card_order = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

sorted_cards = sorted(card_candidates, key=lambda c: (card_order.index(c[0]), c[1]))

print(list(sorted_cards))
```

Output:

```
['3S', '9D', '9S', '0D']
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bGi6e8)

Please note that this approach scans the `card_order` list once for every card to sort each time you sort any card list. This is no problem if you just sort a normal deck of cards at the beginning of a game or even every few seconds. However, if your code is sorting huge numbers of cards or sorting cards most of its time, you might want to prefer the solution by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) which converts the `card_order` list into a dictionary that can be scanned faster.

Comment: The mapping I create avoids the full scan across `card_order` that `list.index` makes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I have to agree. If you have to sort many cards and have to sort them often, it is more efficient to use your approach, as looking up a hash in a dictionary is faster than scanning a list for an item using `index`. But if it only happens once at the start of a game, which would be no time-critical use case, those few milliseconds should not make a difference.

Comment: sure, but this is *Stack Overflow*, where code from your answer will be copied and pasted everywhere. Always explain the tradeoffs of your code, for the few people that read enough of the context to understand. :-) In CS terms, you produced a `O(KNlogN)` sort, mine is still `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added an explanation (although I don't understand how to find out those big O notations). Better now?

Comment: Yup, thanks! As for the big O notation, the Python Wiki [documents the time complexity of many operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity); TimSort (the sorting algorithm used by Python) is O(NlogN), but for every element in the input list you scan up to K elements in `card_order`, making the overall process O(KNlogN).