# Sorting a list with both numbers and letters

Tags: python, sorting

I am a first-year A-Level student and I am trying to sort the list below, which represents a hand in the card game Rummy:

```
hand = [(1, '-', '3', 'Spades'), (2, '-', '8', 'Clubs'), (3, '-', '10', 'Hearts'), (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'), (5, '-', '7', 'Clubs'), (6, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'), (7, '-', '10', 'Spades')]
```

I want it sorted so the suits are in alphabetical order (Clubs, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, Spades, Spades) and where the suit is the same, the card with the lowest value (Ace being lowest, King being highest) comes first. Once sorted, the `index[0]` values, which just gives a reference number to each card when selecting one in other parts of the program, should be essentially re-assigned so they once again read in order from 1 to 7. I want it to be outputted as this:

```
[(1, '-', '7', 'Clubs'), (2, '-', '8', 'Clubs'), (3, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'), (4, '-', '10', 'Hearts'), (5, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'), (6, '-', '3', 'Spades'), (7, '-', '10', 'Spades')]
```

I thought about trying to do something like this:

```
suit_hand = (hand[0][4], hand[1][4], hand[2][4], hand[3][4], hand[4][4], hand[5][4], hand[6][4])
arr = sorted(suit_hand)
```

and then using a standard sorting algorithm, probably an insertion sort, for the card value but I'm not really sure how to go about executing it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting list of cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179737/sorting-list-of-cards)

Comment: @HåkenLid the question is asking a similar question to mine yes, unfortunately the answer is a bit complex for me, I am only a first year A-Level student!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hand = [(1, '-', '3', 'Spades'), (2, '-', '8', 'Clubs'), (3, '-', '10', 'Hearts'), (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'),
        (5, '-', '7', 'Clubs'), (6, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'), (7, '-', '10', 'Spades')]
print(sorted(hand, key=lambda x: x[3]))
```

**Output**

```
[(2, '-', '8', 'Clubs'), (5, '-', '7', 'Clubs'), (6, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'), (3, '-', '10', 'Hearts'), (1, '-', '3', 'Spades'), (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'), (7, '-', '10', 'Spades')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping between the value of each card (`'2': 2, ... 'Ace': 14`) to make the comparison simple:

```
value_rank = {
    **{'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14},
    **{str(i): i for i in range(2, 11)}}

sorted(hand, key=lambda c: (c[3], -value_rank[c[2]]))
# out:
[(2, '-', '8', 'Clubs'),
 (5, '-', '7', 'Clubs'),
 (6, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'),
 (3, '-', '10', 'Hearts'),
 (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'),
 (7, '-', '10', 'Spades'),
 (1, '-', '3', 'Spades')]
```

Oh, and to reassign the card id:

```
>>> [(i,) + c[1:] for i, c in enumerate(sorted(hand, key=lambda c: (c[3], -value_rank[c[2]])))]
[(0, '-', '8', 'Clubs'),
 (1, '-', '7', 'Clubs'),
 (2, '-', 'Queen', 'Diamonds'),
 (3, '-', '10', 'Hearts'),
 (4, '-', 'Ace', 'Spades'),
 (5, '-', '10', 'Spades'),
 (6, '-', '3', 'Spades')]
```

Note however, that you'll get more serviceable code if you invest a bit of time defining a `card` class (a simple `namedtuple` with some `total_ordering`):

```
@total_ordering
class card(namedtuple('Card', 'cid dash value suit')):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.suit, self.value) == (o.suit, o.value)
    
    def __lt__(self, o):
        return (self.suit, -value_rank[self.value]) < (o.suit, -value_rank[o.value])
    
    def with_id(self, cid):
        return card(cid, self.dash, self.value, self.suit)

hand = [card(*c) for c in hand]
[c.with_id(i) for i, c in enumerate(sorted(hand))]
# out:
[card(cid=0, dash='-', value='8', suit='Clubs'),
 card(cid=1, dash='-', value='7', suit='Clubs'),
 card(cid=2, dash='-', value='Queen', suit='Diamonds'),
 card(cid=3, dash='-', value='10', suit='Hearts'),
 card(cid=4, dash='-', value='Ace', suit='Spades'),
 card(cid=5, dash='-', value='10', suit='Spades'),
 card(cid=6, dash='-', value='3', suit='Spades')]
```

Comment: awesome! nice answer!

Comment: instead of declareing a dict i would use a ordered list and index `values = [*range(1,11),'Jack', 'Queen', 'King','Ace']` and `lambda c: (c[3], -values.index(c[2]))`

Comment: @adirabargil: thanks, but looking up the index in a list is `O(n)`, whereas looking up a value in a dict is `O(1)`.

Comment: its not so serious when you talk about list the size of 14...